# How to get a temporary (or permanent) regular URL for a file in OneDrive using the Microsoft Graph API

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

Using [createLink](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createlink), for example with the POST parameters: {"type": "view", "scope": "anonymous"}, you get a response including a **webUrl** which will open the item (in read-only or read-write mode, depending on the POST parameters) in Office Online. Because of the 'anonymous' scope, anyone (no login required) can open the office online page.

Unfortunately, I don't a link to Office Online, and it looks like this is the functionality provided by [Create a sharing link for a DriveItem](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createlink).

I need a link to the actual file (to download it).
Something like many other 'files' APIs allow. This is, generate a time-limited (or permanent) URL to file.

Is this possible?

EDIT: Clarification: [Download the contents of a DriveItem](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_downloadcontent) (i.e. a Stream) is not what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are four ways of linking to a file in OneDrive via Microsoft Graph:

- The web preview for the file, which is accessed from the webUrl property of DriveItem. This requires the user to be signed in to access.
- The WebDAV URL for the file, which is accessed from the webDavUrl property of DriveItem. This also requires the user to be signed in to access, but is a direct link to the file. Note: this is available via Microsoft Graph, but is only documented on [dev.onedrive.com](https://dev.onedrive.com/resources/item.htm).
- [Creating a sharing link](https://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_createlink), which provides anonymous or organization restricted access to the web preview of the file.
- [Download link](http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/item_downloadcontent), which is a short-duration URL available to download the contents of the file programmatically.

It sounds like webDavUrl might be the link you are looking for.