# Microsoft Graph OneDrive Item Preview URL

Tags: .net, microsoft-graph-api, onedrive

I've been trying to get url of drive item, that will open original file in browser (not download, not their preview page). I need that kind of url in order to show image or pass url to pdf view-er. I tried multiple options, creating shared link, preview request, thumbnail request, but I cannot get that type of url. Is there a way to do it, or I'm missing something? The closest one was PreviewRequest, but when I opet that url, it displays images and pdf-s in their "previewer" instead of default browser tab.

These are the things I tried.
[image]

Answer (score 0):

(Since "web url" is not mentioned, assuming that you have not seen it already.)
A [drive item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/resources/driveitem?view=graph-rest-1.0) has the "web url" property with which the file can be opened in the browser. But it will require the user to sign in.
"Preview url" obtained by the [Preview item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-preview?view=graph-rest-1.0) api can be used to view the file, as you mentioned, in "their viewer" and will let anyone to view the file without any need to sign in.
Multiple ways are there to get the web url of a drive item, a common one is using [Get item](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/driveitem-get?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) api. A few other methods to access the file can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/40052868/8913170)
(Links here are to the graph rest api docs and not to the sdks)